# How do I order rows in a specific sequence using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT BookSize(page_count) as Size, count(*) as NmbrBoooks 
    FROM books 
    WHERE page_count IS NOT NULL 
        AND page_count > 0 
    GROUP BY Size;
```

The output is as follows:

```
+-----------+------------+
| Size      | NmbrBoooks |
+-----------+------------+
| ExtraLong |          3 |
| Long      |         11 |
| Medium    |         51 |
| Short     |         27 |
+-----------+------------+
```

I would like to sort this according to the book's length so I have the following row sequence from top to bottom: Short, Medium, Long, ExtraLong.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select BookSize(page_count) as Size, count(*) as NmbrBoooks from books
where page_count is not null and page_count > 0 group by Size order by page_count;
```